# Nested for loop over the same set, remove element from said set

Tags: java, set

I'm writing a program and have encountered a problem when removing a set from a set of sets.

### Problem

Firstly I will outline the desired functionality.

Given a set of sets storing Integer values, such as the following:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

and a list of constraints in the form:

```
((1, 2), (9, 10), (2, 9))
```

For each constraint I am iterating through the sets and merging and removing sets based on the constraint. 
e.g. (1, 2) means 1 and 2 should be in the same set, therefore merge the sets.

After iterating over the constraints, the remaining sets should be:

```
[[1,2,9,10], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

The method in which I have implemented, merges and removes sets okay when there is only one element in the set (at least that is the pattern I have identified).
The constraints are iterated in order and before applying the final constraint, the state of the sets is as follows:

```
[[1,2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9,10]]
```

Upon applying the final constraint (2,9), which means sets containing 2 and 9 should be merged, the code produces the following output:

```
[[1,2,9,10], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9,10]]
```

### Implementation

The following sample program demonstrates this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Set<Integer>> originalSet = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
    Set<Integer> tempSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    //Populate original set with sets of integers 1-10
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        tempSet.add(i);
        originalSet.add(new HashSet<Integer>(tempSet));
        tempSet.clear();
    }

    System.out.println("Original Sets: ");
    for (Set<Integer> set : originalSet) {
        System.out.println(set.toString());
    }

    //Generate constraints
    List<Pair> pairSet = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    pairSet.add(new Pair(1, 2));
    pairSet.add(new Pair(9, 10));
    pairSet.add(new Pair(2, 9));

    System.out.println("Set of Pairs: ");
    for (Pair p : pairSet) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("Merge and Remove Process");
    //For each pair
    for (Pair p : pairSet) {
        System.out.println("Iteration::Merge sets containing " + p.toString());
        boolean merged = false;
        //Iterate over each set in the original set
        for (Set s : originalSet) {
            //If the set contains the first element of the pair and no merge has been performed
            if (s.contains(p.getFirst()) && (merged == false)) {
                //Find the set containing the second element of the pair 
                for (Set t : originalSet) {
                    if (t.contains(p.getSecond())) {
                        //Merge t with s
                        s.addAll(t);
                        originalSet.remove(t);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //s.add(constraint.getB());
                merged = true;
                break;
            }

            //If the set contains the second element of the pair and no merge has been performed
            if (s.contains(p.getSecond()) && (merged == false)) {
                //Find the set containing the first element of the pair 
                for (Set t : originalSet) {
                    if (t.contains(p.getFirst())) {
                        //Merge t with s
                        s.addAll(t);
                        originalSet.remove(t);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //s.add(constraint.getB());
                merged = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //Output the set after update
        for (Set<Integer> set : originalSet) {
            System.out.println(set.toString());
        }
    }

}

public static class Pair<F, S> {

    private F first; //first member of pair
    private S second; //second member of pair

    public Pair(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public void setFirst(F first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public void setSecond(S second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    public F getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public S getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + getFirst() + ", " + getSecond() + ")";
    }
}
}
```

The function to remove a set doesn't seem to work when inside the for loops and I'm not sure why.

```
for (Pair p : pairSet) {
        for (Set s : originalSet) {
                for (Set t : originalSet) {
                   originalSet.remove(t);
                }
        }
}
```

Although the merge seems to work fine.

The output from the program is as follows:

```
Original Sets: 
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[10]
Set of Pairs: 
(1, 2)
(9, 10)
(2, 9)
Merge and Remove Process
Iteration::Merge sets containing (1, 2)
[1, 2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[10]
Iteration::Merge sets containing (9, 10)
[1, 2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9, 10]
Iteration::Merge sets containing (2, 9)
[1, 2, 9, 10]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9, 10]
```

The final set [9, 10] shouldn't exist. 
I appreciate any help in understanding why the remove function doesn't achieve the desired output!

Comment: I'd expect this to fail with a ConcurrentModificationException.  That said, this looks like a use case for a better data structure for the problem, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @LouisWasserman This doesn't fail with that exception, I thought it would also. I'll look into that link, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an Iterator like this mate:

```
package setproblem;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetProblem {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Set<Set<Integer>> originalSet = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
Set<Integer> tempSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

//Populate original set with sets of integers 1-10
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    tempSet.add(i);
    originalSet.add(new HashSet<Integer>(tempSet));
    tempSet.clear();
}

System.out.println("Original Sets: ");
for (Set<Integer> set : originalSet) {
    System.out.println(set.toString());
}

//Generate constraints
List<Pair> pairSet = new LinkedList<Pair>();
pairSet.add(new Pair(1, 2));
pairSet.add(new Pair(9, 10));
pairSet.add(new Pair(2, 9));

System.out.println("Set of Pairs: ");
for (Pair p : pairSet) {
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}

System.out.println("Merge and Remove Process");
//For each pair
for (Pair p : pairSet) {
    System.out.println("Iteration::" + p.toString());

    Set<Integer> firstElementSet = getAllElementsFromOriginalSetContaining((Integer)p.getFirst(), originalSet);
    System.out.println("FES::" + firstElementSet.toString());
    Set<Integer> secondElementSet = getAllElementsFromOriginalSetContaining((Integer)p.getSecond(), originalSet);
    System.out.println("SES::" + secondElementSet.toString());

    removeElements(firstElementSet, originalSet);
    removeElements(secondElementSet, originalSet);

    originalSet.removeAll(firstElementSet);
    originalSet.removeAll(secondElementSet);
    firstElementSet.addAll(secondElementSet);
    originalSet.add(firstElementSet);


    for(Set<Integer> s : originalSet){
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}

}

private static Set<Integer> getAllElementsFromOriginalSetContaining(Integer element, Set<Set<Integer>> originalSet) {

    Set<Integer> tempSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for(Set<Integer> s : originalSet){
        if(s.contains(element)){
            tempSet.addAll(s);
        }
    }

    return new HashSet<Integer>(tempSet);
}

private static void removeElements(Set<Integer> elementSet, Set<Set<Integer>> originalSet) {

    Iterator originalSetIterator = originalSet.iterator();

    while(originalSetIterator.hasNext()) {
        Set<Integer> s = (HashSet<Integer>)originalSetIterator.next();

        if(s.equals(elementSet)){
             System.out.println("Found set! " + elementSet.toString());
              System.out.println("Found in originalSet! " + s.toString());
              originalSetIterator.remove();
        }
    }        
}

public static class Pair<F, S> {

private F first; //first member of pair
private S second; //second member of pair

public Pair(F first, S second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

public void setFirst(F first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public void setSecond(S second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public F getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public S getSecond() {
    return second;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + getFirst() + ", " + getSecond() + ")";
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two nested loops iterating over `originalSet`, modifying the set pulls the rug out from under both iterators.

With just one loop, you could fix it by using an explicit Iterator and calling `iterator.remove()` to remove the current element.

Since that won't work here, you'll have to iterate over a copy of the Set while modifying the original Set, or iterate over the original Set while building up a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Set t : originalSet) {
    if (t.contains(p.getFirst())) {
        //Merge t with s
        s.addAll(t);
        originalSet.remove(t);
        break;
    }
}
```

You cannot remove that in that way, you should use iterator if you want to remove items from collection through which you iterates. Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html